# Avoid unnecessary API Calls React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useMemo with url searchParams, as soon as params get updated it makes an API call.
But when I navigate to a new page using `NavLink` the route has few additional `params`. Due to which another API call is made before navigating to next page.

Code snippet:

```
function updateSearchParams (data: any) {
    ....
    setSearchParams(queryParams);
    return;
}

useEffect(() => {
    setFilters([]);
  }, []);
```

Navigation Component:

```
<Link href="'xyz.com?param=abc">Link</Link>
```

On clicking link route the params get updated and invoke api call.

Is there any way around to stop this extra call before navigating to next page

Comment: please post more codes. Especially how how the `params` are updated in this component

Comment: @windmaomao
thank you for responding to my query, I had a similar issue which is mentioned here hence used work around mentioned on the same link https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7634